# Check Anonimizing IP fun in web source code

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics

Is it possible to check from the browser anonimizing ip function in web source code? And if yes, can I also check if anonimizing function is before tracking website function.
Need this to make sure if I can turn off internal website trafic from google analytic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tracking code snippet will *usually* be configured for anonymizing IP data via the set method, so as to anonymize all hits sent within site pages, and viewable via the source code.

**analytics.js**
if all hits are being anonymized the tracking code snippet should show the following line of code before the send pageview command

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

if only some hits are being anonymized, it will be configured within the hit it is being sent with.
eg a single pageview:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'anonymizeIp': true
});
```

**gtag.js**

```
gtag('config', '<GA_MEASUREMENT_ID>', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

or single event

```
gtag('event', 'your_event', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

Also if you are browsing a site, you can check the dev tools network tab and look for requests sent to google-analytics.com/collect
If GA is anonymizing IP, then the request will contain the aip parameter.
According to the measurement protocol docs:

> the IP will be anonymized if any of the following parameters are
>   present in the payload: &aip=, &aip=0, or &aip=1

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#aip

Answer (score 0):

If you anonymize the IP you cannot filter the actual internal IP from the view.

I suggest you do it from the server side language, so that if the IP is among the internal ones you don't have the tracking code inserted in the pages.